# Doubly linked list maintain sorted list

Tags: c++, list

How can I maintain the list sorted without a sort function. When I add node I want to maintain the list sorted. 
Also when removing a node.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;


struct Node
{
 //node declare
  double value;
  Node *next;
  Node *prev;
  Node(double y)
  {
      value = y;
      next = prev = NULL;
  }
};

class DLinkedList
{
  Node *front;
  Node *back;
  public:
  DLinkedList()
  {  
               front = NULL; back = NULL; 
  }
  //declare function
  void NodeFront(double x);
  void NodeBack(double x);
  void dispForward();
  void dispReverse();
}; 
void DLinkedList::NodeFront(double x)
  {
        Node *n = new Node(x);

        if( front == NULL)
        {
            front = n;
            back = n;
        }
        else
        {
            front->prev = n;
            n->next = front;
            front = n;}

  }
  void DLinkedList::NodeBack(double x)
  {
        Node *n = new Node(x);
        if( back == NULL)
        {
            front = n;
            back = n;
        }
        else
        {
            back->next = n;
            n->prev = back;
            back = n;

        }

}
 //forward nodes
  void DLinkedList::dispForward()
  {
      Node *temp = front;
      cout << "forward order:" << endl;
      while(temp != NULL)
      {
         cout << temp->value << " " ;
         cout<<endl;
         temp = temp->next;
      }
  }
  //reverse list
  void DLinkedList::dispReverse()
  {
      Node *temp = back;
      cout << "reverse order :" << endl;
      while(temp != NULL)
      {
         cout << temp->value << " " ;
         cout<<endl;
         temp = temp->prev;
      }
  }

int main()
{
    DLinkedList *list = new DLinkedList();
    //front of the list
    list->NodeFront(45.0);
    list->NodeFront(49.0);
    list->NodeFront(42.0);
    list->NodeFront(48.0);
    list->NodeFront(48.0);
    list->NodeFront(52.0);
    list->NodeFront(12.0);
    list->NodeFront(100.0);

    list->dispForward();
    list->dispReverse();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A linked list is really the wrong data structure if you want to maintain sorted keys

Comment: Smells like either a homework or somebody who doesn't know about `std::list`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a new function:

```
  void DLinkedList::NodeSorted(double x)
  {
        Node *n = new Node(x);

        // Step 1:  Find the first node "x" that should be AFTER n.

        // Step 2:  Make the node before "x" link to n

        // Step 2:  Make "x" link to n

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain it sorted pretty easy. Add another method NodeSorted (bad name, I just followed your convention, they should be insertFront, insertBack, insertSorted instead).
What this method should do - insert node into proper position, so you go through your list and as soon as find element greater than what you need to insert, insert your node before it. Be aware for such NodeSorted to work properly you need to maintain list sorted, ie avoid using NodeFront and NodeFront. Of course NodeSorted itself if implemented properly will maintain list in sorted state.